# Is the Karite sect and their religion on topic?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

It seems there are questions that pop up here and there concerning Karites and their  religion. Are they on topic here at Mi Yodea, a site dedicated to traditional Judaism? Should we include all splinter groups that Chazzal called Minim such as Christianity?